# Ember Two-way data binding with parser

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm new to ember—loving it so far.

I'm using Ember-data, and I have an attribute that needs to contain some structured JSON. However, I want to use a `textarea` to edit this attribute. The `textarea` should not display the `JSON` "as `JSON`" but according to some other arbitrary criteria. For example, if I wanted to save `CSV` data as `JSON` (each line is an array of strings, or the like), but display it as CSV. I've built something similar in Angular utilizing the `$parser` and `$formatter` functions in a directive, but I don't know how to tackle this in Ember.

Surely there's a good way to do this, I just have no clue where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [computed property](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/) therefore:

```
export default Ember.Object.extend({
  data: DS.attr('json'),

  dataAsCsv: function(key, value, previousValue){
    // setter
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      this.set('data', csvToJson( value.toJson );
    }

    // getter
    return jsonToCsv( this.get('data') );
  }.property('data')
});
```